# how to fix this issues in react mern applicationn

Tags: reactjs, mern

Hi everybody please help me, a create my app with npx create-react-app

I was peacefully coding my MERN application when suddenly this error popped up out of nowhere, without me having done or modified anything. I really don't understand anything about it, I don't even know where it's coming from. I've been searching for over 7 hours and found no similar results, even with ChatGPT. Please, help me! Here's the error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js 201:12-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/Users/macbookpro/Documents/GitHub/social/client/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js 21:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/macbookpro/Documents/GitHub/social/client/node_modules/content-disposition'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

and more and more error

Help me please and thank you

i tried to find in google a solution but all solution send me to webpack.config.js and i don't found it in my files of project

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit vague answer but has helped me resolve similar issues in the past. Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and then doing `npm install` might help.
If that doesn't fix do `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
it could be because of node version.

Another possible solution, I have used yarn install after deleting package-lock.json and node_modeules. Yarn seems to give lees of these issues with packages

Comment: thank's for answer but it's doesn't works :(

Comment: next check is make sure you have all modules that are needed. do `npm instal`l for everything that says module not found

Answer (score 0):

'BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.'

Polyfills are just to help fill in the blanks on old browsers, by creating a fall back. Because you have updated webpack (I assume in your last npm install), you need to add them. Side note: why are you not using a webpack.config.js?

Whether you npm install the relevant polyfills, 'path-browserify' and 'querystring-es3' or not, you need to **create** a webpack.config.js as the only other alternative is rolling back your webpack version to something before 5 (which may break your project as well). Here is a sample webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js', // Entry point of your application
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Output directory
    filename: 'bundle.js', // Output bundle file name
    publicPath: '/' // Public URL of the output directory
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] // Allow importing JS/JSX files without specifying their extensions
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html', // HTML template file
      filename: 'index.html' // Output HTML file name
    })
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hii finally i found the webpack.config inn react-scripts what i have ti do now